# What does KSQL WARN Warning: window end time was truncated to Long.MAX mean?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I get ksql WARN Warning: window end time was truncated to Long.MAX in ksql-server.stdout.

I would like to know in which occasion this warning is fired and the degree of importance, as the query that generate this warning also provides the expected result from a functional perspective.

reviewed ksql source code - trying to understand the intended meaning of the handled warning and its degree of importance

query works ok - just have this warning WARN Warning: window end time was truncated to Long.MAX in ksql-server.stdout.

Answer (score 0):

This warning log line is output deserializing a tumbling or hopping windowed key if the computed end time of the window is out of bounds.

The only time you should see this warning is when using the `PRINT topic` command. See https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/5458 for details.

If you're seeing this warning during normal processing of data, i.e. when not using the `PRINT` command, then it could be that you've imported streams with windowed keys, i.e. using `WINDOW_TYPE='hopping'` or `WINDOW_TYPE='tumbling'` with the wrong window size `WINDOW_SIZE`, or where the underlying source topic does not have time-windowed keys.